# USB Serial driver not mapped to the /dev/ttyUSBO serial port

Tags: drivers, usb, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04

The cp210x usb to uart on arduino board is not getting mapped to the /dev/ttyUSBO serial port.

I plugged in the board and ran dmesg:

```
18159.799449] usb 4-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[18160.014582] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60, bcdDevice= 1.00
[18160.014586] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[18160.014588] usb 4-1: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[18160.014590] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[18160.014592] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 0001
[18160.100924] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[18160.100936] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[18160.114921] cp210x: version magic '5.4.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload ' should be '5.4.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload '
```

Issue with driver version?

Answer (score 1):

USB serial devices can also be mounted under different names such as `/dev/ttyACM0`. You should see all the names of the usb serial devices by running

```
$ ls /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/
ttyUSB0
```

This means I have a USB serial device on `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-56-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/cp210x
```

then edit `/sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/cp210x/new_id`
and add the manufacturer device code (found with lsusb):

```
10c4 0004
```